# How to update content div from an external page without refreshing - GAE

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine

Well, I'm developing an application in GAE with python and basically what I need is a way to emulate a chat in a many-to-one pages. The many pages can send messages to the single page.

I looked for sockets but I get problems when I work with local ports (in all ports I tried I've got an access denied message), they only worked on console application and I need this working on web. Then I looked for an AJAX solution but I can't still find that final part in which, after a message has been submitted, the content of the page that is going to receive all the messages has to be updated.

Does anyone has an idea how to deal with this? I'm also open to suggestions for a different implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Google App Engine Channels ?
I think it is exactly what you are looking for: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/